# Characteristic Ka X-rays

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, x-rays, elements

In an experiment one observes the characteristic Ka X-rays of two elements at
energies of 6.930 and 7.478 eV. The higher energy line is due to Ni. What
element is responsible for the lower energy line?

Comment: This a homework style question. Please show us your own efforts/research. Forum rules!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some points here.

1. If you just treat $K_\alpha$-rays as a transition from principal number 2 to 1, $\Delta E \approx \frac{3}{4}Z^2$ Hartree, which has unit of keV when $Z>10$.
2. Use characteristic Moseley's law, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley%27s_law setting $k_1, k_2$ appropriately and using $ \Delta E = h \Delta f=hf_{\text moseley}$.

Then you can get responsible proton number $Z$.

Comment: It did not work , z=√(4/3)(ΔE/13.6))=0.8

Comment: @JejeZzz Yes, because $K_\alpha$ rays are not the transition from principal number 2 to 1 merely. It's just a low-level approximation to remind you about units you should use. Check wikipedia document again and calculate $\Delta E$ using $f_{\text moseley}$ derived in it.